# Overwriting the Array constructor does not affect [], right?

Tags: javascript, security, arrays, xss

I just read this: **http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx**

I was under the impression that overwriting **`Object`** or **`Array`** only had an effect if you chose to use the constructor functions when creating **`arrays`**/**`objects`**, but, according to that article, it also has an effect on literal creation (**`{}`** and **`[]`**)...

My logic:

```
Array = function(){ alert('Hi'); };

[1,2,3,4,5];
([1,2,3,4,5]);
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];

// ...
// ... Nothing is alerted
```

So, am I going crazy or are there some implementation-specific quirks I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know this is an issue with the ECMAScript specification and was fixed in all major browsers over a year ago. [Here](http://ejohn.org/blog/re-securing-json/) is a link that links you to the most relevant links ;)

But to actually answer your question, yes, the `Object` and `Array` constructors are also invoked for literal creations. The *fix* browsers implemented just made these (and others) constant so they can't be overridden by custom scripts.

Answer (score 5):

The EcmaScript 5 draft standardizes this fix Josef mentions.  It specifies the behavior of the array constructor in terms of the value of the Array global at the time the context was created as described in section 11.1.4.

> Semantics
>
> The production  `ArrayLiteral :  [ Elisionopt ]`  is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let array be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression
>    `new Array()` where `Array` is the standard built-in constructor with that name.

Instead of the old ES 262 behavior which allowed for replacing the Array constructor:

> Semantics
>
> The production `ArrayLiteral : [ Elisionopt ]` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Create a new array as if by the expression `new Array()`.

That said, do not rely on `[]` working sensibly on older interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

By setting Array to be a function you are not overriding the constructor of arrays, but instead replacing the function.

To correctly override the constructor you would use the Array.prototype.**defineSetter** to set the method being called on construction, and this would be called both on new Array() and when using the literal notation.

Comment: Not true according to section 11.4.1 of the EcmaScript 262 specification.