# Override globals in modern browsers

Tags: javascript, json, security

I just read the [John Resig article](http://ejohn.org/blog/re-securing-json/) about overriding the globals in browser (e.g. Array) but when I try that example in my browser, nothing happend.

Here the code:

```
var sec = {};
function Array() { 
    alert(1); 
    sec = this; 
};
```

and when I run `["zdxc", "sd", 1111, 11.1]` in my browser's console, nothing happend. Array declared and no alert shown.

Is that a bug that fixed in modern browsers or it's still works in some version of browsers?

Comment: it will only work on `var a = new Array();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you override the Array-contructor which makes the call `new Array();` return your custom object insted of an actual `Array`.

So calling

```
var arr = ["zdxc", "sd", 1111, 11.1];
```

makes `arr` beeing a native `Array`.

Calling

```
var arr_override = new Array();
```

makes `arr_override` beeing an `Object` of the type you declared before and therefore executing your `alert`-statement. Overriding the constructor kind of "erases" the `Array`-initialisation from the identifier replacing it with your constructor function. Its not an actual `Array`.

According to [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053556/overwriting-the-array-constructor-does-not-affect-right) the Array-Literal (`[]`) is not beeing affected by this behaviour since about 2008 in all mayor browsers..

**EDIT:**

After trying around a bit it does not seem to be possible to modify the behaviour of the `[]`-notation and it is not recomended either to modify Native Objects (expecially their constructors) at all btw.

How ever it is possible to extend the prototypes and also to modify existing properties/methods like in the example below

```
var arr = [];
arr.push('2323');
alert(arr);

Array.prototype.push = function() { alert('trololololo'); }
arr.push(123);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your response, so is that mean we can't modify Array-literal (`[]`) anymore?