# Hooking Arrays created via array literal

Tags: javascript

I'm essentially looking for a way to run some logic on any array created on a page, for example, to check that the contents match some pattern and if they do, expose the array to the global scope.

Currently I have this snippet:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 0, {
    get: function() {console.log("Got em"); window.someArray = this; return 0;},
    set: function() {console.log("Got em again")}
});
```

So when this is run:

```
(function() {
    let test = [];
    test[0];
})();
```

The message "Got em" is logged and the array is exposed.

However, running:

```
(function() {
    let test = ["hello", "world"];
    test[0];
})();
```

Gives no log output nor is the array exposed.

Is there any way to make that second case work? My understanding from this question: [Overwriting the Array constructor does not affect [], right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053556/overwriting-the-array-constructor-does-not-affect-right) is that the array literal construction cannot be overridden. I'm willing to go as far as modifying V8 source to allow such an override but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: The getter gives me a stack overflow. Maybe a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) would be a better solution.

Comment: this leads to infinte loop

Comment: dont you think, array property should be like this: `Array.prototype.getArray = function(){ 
    console.log("got em");
    window.GlobalArray = this;
    return false;
}`

Comment: @MarkMeyer not sure how you're getting a SO

Answer (score 0):

okay, I find the basic answer, how to deal with this problem

```
 Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'push', {

     value: function(){ 
            // rest of the code as Array API give to push the array
              console.log("hello world ");
            }
      });
```

and when we create an array and push; this works

like

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("Hi Jarvis");
```

output

```
Hello World
```

```js
 Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'push', {
     
     value: function(){ 
            // rest of the code as Array API give to push the array
              console.log("hello world ");
            }
      });

var arr = [];
arr.push("Hi Jarvis");
console.log(arr);
```

But the issue is, we have to find the Array API's push code, so that push works flawlessly

```js
function ObservableArray(items) {
  var _self = this,
    _array = [],
    _handlers = {
      itemadded: [],
      itemremoved: [],
      itemset: []
    };

  function defineIndexProperty(index) {
    if (!(index in _self)) {
      Object.defineProperty(_self, index, {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        get: function() {
          return _array[index];
        },
        set: function(v) {
          _array[index] = v;
          raiseEvent({
            type: "itemset",
            index: index,
            item: v
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function raiseEvent(event) {
    _handlers[event.type].forEach(function(h) {
      h.call(_self, event);
    });
  }

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "addEventListener", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(eventName, handler) {
      eventName = ("" + eventName).toLowerCase();
      if (!(eventName in _handlers)) throw new Error("Invalid event name.");
      if (typeof handler !== "function") throw new Error("Invalid handler.");
      _handlers[eventName].push(handler);
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "removeEventListener", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(eventName, handler) {
      eventName = ("" + eventName).toLowerCase();
      if (!(eventName in _handlers)) throw new Error("Invalid event name.");
      if (typeof handler !== "function") throw new Error("Invalid handler.");
      var h = _handlers[eventName];
      var ln = h.length;
      while (--ln >= 0) {
        if (h[ln] === handler) {
          h.splice(ln, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "push", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
      var index;
      for (var i = 0, ln = arguments.length; i < ln; i++) {
        index = _array.length;
        _array.push(arguments[i]);
        defineIndexProperty(index);
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemadded",
          index: index,
          item: arguments[i]
        });
      }
      return _array.length;
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "pop", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
      if (_array.length > -1) {
        var index = _array.length - 1,
          item = _array.pop();
        delete _self[index];
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemremoved",
          index: index,
          item: item
        });
        return item;
      }
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "unshift", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
      for (var i = 0, ln = arguments.length; i < ln; i++) {
        _array.splice(i, 0, arguments[i]);
        defineIndexProperty(_array.length - 1);
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemadded",
          index: i,
          item: arguments[i]
        });
      }
      for (; i < _array.length; i++) {
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemset",
          index: i,
          item: _array[i]
        });
      }
      return _array.length;
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "shift", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function() {
      if (_array.length > -1) {
        var item = _array.shift();
        delete _self[_array.length];
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemremoved",
          index: 0,
          item: item
        });
        return item;
      }
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "splice", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(index, howMany /*, element1, element2, ... */ ) {
      var removed = [],
          item,
          pos;

      index = index == null ? 0 : index < 0 ? _array.length + index : index;

      howMany = howMany == null ? _array.length - index : howMany > 0 ? howMany : 0;

      while (howMany--) {
        item = _array.splice(index, 1)[0];
        removed.push(item);
        delete _self[_array.length];
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemremoved",
          index: index + removed.length - 1,
          item: item
        });
      }

      for (var i = 2, ln = arguments.length; i < ln; i++) {
        _array.splice(index, 0, arguments[i]);
        defineIndexProperty(_array.length - 1);
        raiseEvent({
          type: "itemadded",
          index: index,
          item: arguments[i]
        });
        index++;
      }

      return removed;
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(_self, "length", {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    get: function() {
      return _array.length;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      var n = Number(value);
      var length = _array.length;
      if (n % 1 === 0 && n >= 0) {        
        if (n < length) {
          _self.splice(n);
        } else if (n > length) {
          _self.push.apply(_self, new Array(n - length));
        }
      } else {
        throw new RangeError("Invalid array length");
      }
      _array.length = n;
      return value;
    }
  });

  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype).forEach(function(name) {
    if (!(name in _self)) {
      Object.defineProperty(_self, name, {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false,
        value: Array.prototype[name]
      });
    }
  });

  if (items instanceof Array) {
    _self.push.apply(_self, items);
  }
}

(function testing() {

  var x = new ObservableArray(["a", "b", "c", "d"]);

  console.log("original array : " + x);
  console.log("original array: %o", x.slice());

  x.addEventListener("itemadded", function(e) {
    console.log("Added %o at index %d.", e.item, e.index);
  });

  x.addEventListener("itemset", function(e) {
    console.log("Set index %d to %o.", e.index, e.item);
  });

  x.addEventListener("itemremoved", function(e) {
    console.log("Removed %o at index %d.", e.item, e.index);
  });
 
  console.log("popping and unshifting...");
  x.unshift(x.pop());

  console.log("updated array: %o", x.slice());

  console.log("reversing array...");
  console.log("updated array: %o", x.reverse().slice());

  console.log("splicing...");
  x.splice(1, 2, "x");
  console.log("setting index 2...");
  x[2] = "foo";

  console.log("setting length to 10...");
  x.length = 10;
  console.log("updated array: %o", x.slice());

  console.log("setting length to 2...");
  x.length = 2;

  console.log("extracting first element via shift()");
  x.shift();

  console.log("updated array: %o", x.slice());

})();
```

this is other code, which helps to maintains the array other functions working too!